# link on a bootstrap glyphicon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following rails code

```
<%= link_to mypath do %>
    <%= content_tag(:i, "" ,:class=>' icon-eye-open' %>
<% end %>
<%= @num %>
```

which generates the html

```
<a href="/mypath">
    <i class=" icon-eye-open"></i>
</a>
100
```

The problem is, as seen in the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/guyisra/ntgPK/), that when mousing over the icon, there is a space underlined between the number and the icon. The space is needed for visual purposes, but how do I remove the underline of the link without css?

Why without? I could do `text-decoration: none;` for some css selector, specific or generic, but I want to understand why this underline happens.
If the `@num` is removed, there is no underline, and since it is outside of the anchor tag, it shouldn't affect it. Yet, it obviously does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is happening due to the whitespace *after* the `</i>`

Try switching your code in the jsFiddle to:

```
<a href="/mypath"><i class=" icon-eye-open"></i></a>100
```

and the problem goes away.

This is because the `<i>` element is *inline* (or rather, *inline-block*), which means whitespace is, as a rule, significant.

---

To prevent ERB from including a newline after a tag close it with a trailing `-%>`, ie:

```
<%= content_tag(:i, "" ,:class=>' icon-eye-open' -%>
```

Comment: the html is automatically generated by rails, what is the difference between the html version? making it less tidy?

Comment: ok I'll accept it since it did lead me to solve it. If I close the content_tag with ```-%>``` it leads to the same result, without the whitespace. thanks!

Comment: @NickGinanto I'll add your solution to the answer :)